# access javascript variable in php function

Tags: javascript, php

I want to use `javascript variable` in php code. How to do that? I want to use the variable `X` in php to get data from database.

```
<script>

 function changeTest(obj){
  var x=obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value);
  }

</script>

<table border="1" id="table">
<tr><td>
<select name="level" onChange="changeTest(this)">
    <option value="A" selected="selected">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this problem, you need to fix a few issues with your code. First, the table tag is never closed, but you probably don't need the table tag in this context anyways. Secondly in order to make this functional, you should enclose the select in a form tag as this is the most simple way of accomplishing your task.

---

### Sample

```
<form method="post" action="URL_OF_PHP_PAGE.PHP">
    <select name="level" onchange="changeTest(this)">
        <option value="A" selected="selected">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

---

In the previous code sample, you should change the action attribute value to the PHP page which will be processing this request. That being said, you can use the `$_POST[]` variable in your php code to access the value of the select. Given that the name of the select is called "*level*", you should use `$_POST["level"]` to access the value of the select on the server.

In terms of accessing a database, you have not given enough information on what you are using in order for me to help. However, that problem may be beyond the scope of this question as it requires some rather extensive setup.